# need help Implementing circular vertical scroller in jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a list of items grouped in a table, let's say 30 and what i want to do is the following:

- scrolling automatically and vertically from bottom to top ,without buttons clicks or mouse events

And here's the code i used:

```
        function scrolling(){
            $('#scrollup table').animate(
            { 
                top: '-=10'
            },
            1000,
            'linear',
            function(){

                      if($('#scrollup table  tr:last').offset().top<0){
                     $('#scrollup table  tr:first').remove();   
                    $('#scrollup table  tr:last').after('<tr>'+$('#scrollup table  tr:first').html()+'</tr>');
                }
            }
        );
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval('scrolling()',200)
        });
```

Can you tell me what I missed or where is the problem ?

Comment: Wish i could give @dystroy a +1 for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code:

```
  function scrolling(){
        var table = $('#scrollup table');
        table.animate(
        { 
            top: '-=5'
        },
        200,
        'linear',
        function(){                
            if($('#scrollup table tr:first').height() <= -parseFloat(table.css("top"))){
                 $('#scrollup table').css("top", 0);
                 $('#scrollup table  tr:last').after($('#scrollup table tr:first').detach());
            }
        }
    );
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval('scrolling()',200)
    });​
```

It works fine ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Jcm/1/)), but will be good only if all rows have equal height. I'm trying to find better solution which will work for diff height rows. Basically, problem with your code is that you always move table up (with `.animate`), but remove first line and add it to the end of table (so table height does not grow up)

**Upd**
Code is updated to work with diff height lines. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Jcm/3/)

Comment: Another issue that i encountred, i need to scroll 2 items at a time and i don't know how i can acheive that, i mean with one item it was easy since i use: tr:first but with 2 , i can't see how, please help

Comment: First - are you sure you need to scroll 2 items (can't imagine why you may need it)? Second - take a look at [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector which should help you to take first and second items.

Comment: but when i can use it ? something like : table.animate(
        { 
            top: '-=$(tr:eq(1))'
        }

Comment: Frankly speaking I do not understand what do you mean under "scroll 2 items at a time". Just move two items at the bottom at the same time? But why do you need that? try to explain what exactly do you need. Maybe it is better to post another question.

Comment: `table.animate( { top: '-=' + $(tr:eq(0)).height() + $(tr:eq(1)).height() }` - try this. But you will also need to move both first and second items in callback, not only the first one

Comment: Firt, i apologize for not making myself clear, what i need is to remove 2 items at a time from bottom instead of one item at each ,right now in every 2 seconds (for example) the first item of the list is removed and the one coming after it (the second) is going up so is the third and the fourth and so on, what i need to do is to make the first and the second in one duration disapear and the 3rd + the 4th goes up, after 2 secs, the 3rd & the 4th dispear from the list and the 5th & 6th replace and so on, hope it's much clearer now

Comment: see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Jcm/4/). It will take two items from top (when both are not visible already) and move those items to bottom

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it still take one single item from top

Comment: Why do you think so? There are two lines `$('#scrollup table  tr:last').after($('#scrollup table tr:first').detach());` first will take first item and move it to bottom. Second will do the same, but now will move first item which was second initially.